# How to get selected value on Dropdown component in office-ui-fabric-react?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

I am trying to use `office-ui-fabric-react` with my project. But I stucked when controlling select input. I want to get selected item's value on OnChange event. But there's no `value` on `event.target`. This seems `div` so it has only `textContent`. Am I have to use `ref`? But I am not happy when I use `ref` because I believe it is not react-way.

Library: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/dropdown

```
  <Dropdown
      label={'Dropdown'}
      onChange={e => {
          // Not working.
          console.log(e.target.value)
      }}
      options={[
          { text: 'A', key: 'keyA'}, 
          { text: 'B', key: 'keyB'}
      ]}
   />
```

1. Is there any solution that without using ref?
2. If I have to use ref how should I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OMG.. I should read document carefully there's second param.

```
<Dropdown
      label={'Dropdown'}
      onChange={(e, selectedOption) => {
          // Now I can access with `selectedOption`
      }}
      options={[
          { text: 'A', key: 'keyA'}, 
          { text: 'B', key: 'keyB'}
      ]}
   />
```

Comment: Thank you for reading the documentation carefully for all of us that find our way here :D

Comment: Where did you see it in the documentation?

Comment: @OferGal https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dropdown#implementation 
(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLDivElement>, option?: IDropdownOption, index?: number) => void